# Python REGEX matching a multiline with carriage return

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk
```

or

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0\r\n
Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Length: 55\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
id=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk\r\n
```

or

```
POST / HTTP/1.1^M
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0^M
Host: 127.0.0.1^M
Accept: */*^M
Content-Length: 55^M
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded^M
^M
id=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk^M
```

how can I match the `id=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk` string only? I mean anything printable between `two end of lines` (`\r\n or ^M`) and next `end of line` (`\r\n or ^M`)
I tried something like:

```
re.findall(r'^>([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]([a-zA-Z0-9=%&\r\n]+)', buf, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

but no match. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have `>` at the beginning of your regex. This is what is preventing you from getting any matches at all. If you now remove it, there are a lot of matches which you do not seem to need.

I would suggest:

```
(?<![\r\n])(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}[^\r\n]+
```

Which ensures that you have only 2 consecutive newlines (either two `\r\n`, `\r`, or `\n`) before the line you're trying to match. The negative lookbehind `(?<![\r\n])` is what enforces it (it fails the match if there's a newline/carriage return character before the two consecutive newlines).

The above regex doesn't really need the multiline and dotall flags, so you can drop them in this instance if you want to.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pO3aR8)

---

EDIT: Since the `\r`, `\n` and `^M` are not metacharacters, I would suggest this:

```
(?<![\r\n])(?:(?:\\r\\n|\^M)?(?:\r\n|\r|\n)){2}((?:(?!\\r\\?n?|\\n|\^M)[^\r\n\x00])+)(?:\\r\\n|\^M)?
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pY6mD2)

Comment: Hmm, that gives me something like `['\r\n\r\nid=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...']` (snip) any idea why?

Comment: @xtmtrx huh, you have null characters in your file. `\x00` is a null character by the way. I'm not entirely familiar with using unicode characters in regex, but could you try: `(?<![\r\n])(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}[^\r\n\x00]+` instead (I added `\x00` near the end).

Comment: With `found_rx += re.findall(r'(?<![\r\n])(?:\r\n){2}[^\r\n\x00]+', buf, re.MULTILINE)` I get: `['\r\n\r\nid=1234&var=test&nextvar=hh%20hg&anothervar=BB55SSKKKkk']`, I have removed the `|\r|\n` why I still get the first two `\r\n` in my string?

Comment: @xtmtrx Oh, those are literal characters? I thought they were meta characters. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(?:(?:\^M)|[\n\r])+(id=.*)(?=(?:\^M)|[\n\r])
```

**[Check online DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cG3kG8)**

**Explanation**

[image]

Comment: This won't match anything at all. `id=` is an example could be anything.